# How can I wait the finish of a block before executing the next one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I'm having trouble with semaphore.
I have a serie of blocks and I want a block is executed just when the previous one has been finished its work.
I red that I have to play with gcd semaphore but the app stop working at the point signed in the  code and it never enters in the block completation.

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

NSLog(@"1. AZIENDE: BEGIN");
[Model syncAziende:^(id response, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    NSLog(@"2. AZIENDE: FINISH");
}];

/*BLOCKS HERE */dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

NSLog(@"3. AZIENDE: BEGIN");
[Model syncContatti:^(id response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"4. AZIENDE: FINISH");
}];
```

Here's the output:

2014-03-26 09:35:56.561 NSalesCDC[1071:60b] 1. AZIENDE: BEGIN

Comment: Since the `"2. AZIENDE: FINISH"` isn't getting logged, it's clear that the first block is never getting executed. This has nothing to do with the semaphore. The problem is in the `-syncAziende:` method. Also, if you want something to be done after the code in the first block, why not just put it into the first block after the code that's there?

Comment: Because I have 15 blocks: http://imgur.com/4408QQU .

Comment: wow!, never seen such tree in my life :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use semaphores is not the correct approach to this.
Instead, chain your callbacks together. You can create your blocks outside of each other to prevent horrible, pyramid-like callback hell.

This should work for you:

```
// The block that is called when syncContatti: is complete
void (^contattiBlock)(id, NSError *) = ^(id response, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"4. AZIENDE: FINISH");
};

// The block that is called when syncAziende: is complete
void (^aziendeBlock)(id, NSError *) = ^(id response, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"2. AZIENDE: FINISH");
   // Now, we know that syncAziende: is finished, we can start the next step
   [Model syncContatti:conCattiBlock];
};

// Now we begin the entire chain of events
NSLog(@"1. AZIENDE: BEGIN");
[Model syncAziende:aziendeBlock];
```

One downside of this is that you have to define your blocks in reverse-order, but that's not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dispatch_barrier_async()`. `dispatch_barrier_async()` will wait until all the tasks that are scheduled before the barrier to finish execution and then it will start execution. All the tasks scheduled after the barrier will wait for the barrier to finish.

```
dispatch_async(myQueue,
// this will start working now
});

dispatch_barrier_async(myQueue,
// this will wait until the previous block finish 
//and will block the next one from execution
})

dispatch_async(myQueue,
// this will wait for the barrier to finish
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use NSOperation dependencies.
E.g.

```
NSOperationQueue * que = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSBlockOperation * op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"first");
}];
NSBlockOperation * op2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"second");
}];
[op2 addDependency:op];
[que addOperations:@[op,op2] waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

You can also call the second block within the first or use other guys approaches

Comment: The dispatch groups approach doesn't serialize the tasks. They'll run concurrently.

Comment: oops, sorry..really, this is similar to how dispath_apply works

Answer (score 0):

If your reply to my comment above really is the structure of your code, it cries out for refactoring. The repetition is a good candidate for abstraction.

Perhaps something like:

```
static const struct {
    SEL selector;
    NSString* message;
} steps[] = {
    { @selector(syncAziende:), @"Sincrinizzo i contatti" }.
    { @selector(syncContatti:), @"Sincrinizzo le destinazioni" }.
    // ...
};

- (void) doStep:(int) step
{
    if (step < sizeof(steps) / sizeof(steps[0]))
    {
        [Model performSelector:steps[step].selector withObject:[^(id response, NSError *error){
            hud.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d: %@", step + 1, sizeof(steps) / sizeof(steps[0]), steps[step].message];
            [self doStep:step + 1];
        } copy]];
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
            hud.labelText = @"Sincronizzazione terminata";
            [hud hide:YES afterDelay:1.5];
        });
    }
}

...
    [self doStep:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way:

```
- (void) testSomethingAPI
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [Model syncAziende: ^(id response, NSError *error)
    {
        // Your Stuff here...

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];

    while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW))
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 1.f]];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the most godawful way to use a semaphore that I have ever seen. It combines recursive use of the run loop with busy waiting. This code _will_ hurt you. Usually people say "don't do this at home". I'll say do this in the safety of your own home as much as you like, but not in code that other people are going to use.